# Cloud Functions Not Downloading Dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a Node.js app on Google Cloud Functions but it seems that it is not downloading any of my dependencies.  Whenever my code hits a `require` line, it throws the following error:

```
Deployment failure:
Function load error: Code in file app.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'googleapis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/app.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

My `package.json` dependencies block:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.0.9",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-healthcheck": "^0.1.0",
    "googleapis": "^19.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "newrelic": "^1.40.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "string-format": "^0.5.0",
    "universal-analytics": "^0.4.13",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
```

Is there a way to force the install, or is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?  I get no errors running the `functions` package locally via the command `functions deploy runApp --trigger-http` and can do everything I want via my local computer.  The error only happens when trying to set it up in the cloud

I also tried via the `gcloud beta functions` CLI using the `--verbose` flag as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653034/6061661) and I got the following trace:

```
DEBUG: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Error in the build environment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 789, in Execute
resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 754, in Run
resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 482, in Run
return self._UpdateFunction(location, function)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 364, in CatchHTTPErrorRaiseHTTPExceptionFn
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 441, in _UpdateFunction
operations.Wait(op, messages, client, _DEPLOY_WAIT_NOTICE)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 108, in Wait
_WaitForOperation(client, request, notice)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 83, in _WaitForOperation
sleep_ms=SLEEP_MS)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 212, in RetryOnResult
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 47, in _GetOperationStatus
raise exceptions.FunctionsError(util.GetOperationError(op.error))
FunctionsError: OperationError: code=13, message=Error in the build environment
```

Comment: Try to update googleapis package version. The last version is 21.3.0, maybe this is something with package resolving.

Comment: I added how I got it working below but I could completely remove `googleapis` from my app and it would just fail at the next `require` statement and say that package wasn't valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by simply removing `"express-healthcheck": "^0.1.0"`.  I'm not sure why that was causing it to break but since it is Cloud Functions I don't actually need anything related to Express anymore so removing wasn't a problem for my use case.

If anyone knows why this was causing an error please post here, I am curious